# Amazon Web Service: API to get today's date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native

How can I get current UTC date from some web server or Amazon AWS. I am developing app using `react-native` (which is a JavaScript framework) integrated with Amazon AWS.

I have researched and came to know that using `Date()` I can get date. For example :-

```
var today = new Date();
console.log(today);
```

Above retrieves date from the system (mobile). If I change the local system date, I can change the output. This is not what I want.

Is there any Amazon AWS API that I can use in my app, which guarantees returning current date and which can't be manipulated by user changing their local system date? **I want to call that API from my `react-native` code to query today's date.**

If not Amazon AWS, I am open to any other web server API.

Comment: You could try using [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) and a public time server (see ntp.org). However, your question is very unclear as to what you want to achieve. There is no minimal example of code and (as far as I can see) no real issue that couldn't have been solved by a simple search on the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a service to get the date in AWS. You can call [World Clock API - UTC](http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now) to get the current date.

Comment: OK Thanks. But is it 'stable' using it for long run? Is this suitable for production?

Comment: I don't know that I'd trust it for that, given that it says "Alpha" on the main page and they don't have any information. You can do a pretty simple web search to see if you can find a service that is more stable, or you can write your own. A very simple Lambda behind a HTTP API would do the trick if you wanted to go that route.